# dial USSD code from iphone programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone

How to dial `USSD` code for iphone programmatically?

I searched and found that `iOS 7` has already blocked use of `USSD` code for security reason and in iPhones with < iOS7 we can dial a USSD code manualy but not programmatically.

Any one have an idea, can we call USSD programmatically like:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:\*123* <2334555>#"]]`?

Comment: For future reference, it would be quicker to fire up Xcode and test that one line of code rather than ask here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot dial a number containing * or # characters. Apple doesn't allow them in a dial string for security reasons.

[Apple Documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1) :

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing
>   the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports most, but
>   not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if
>   a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt
>   to dial the corresponding phone number. If your app receives URL
>   strings from the user or an unknown source, you should also make sure
>   that any special characters that might not be appropriate in a URL are
>   escaped properly. For native apps, use the
>   stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: method of NSString to
>   escape characters, which returns a properly escaped version of your
>   original string.

Comment: I read apple website too But I get confused because I could dial *1# with code so how is it possible ????

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use `openURL` to programmatically dial USSD codes. Doing so returns `NO`.