# Programmatic USSD in Worklight

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, ussd

Recent Worklight version supports USSD communication from client to adapter. It is quite interesting option for occasional client-server communication when missing internet connection. What bothers me however is programmatic support and here comes my questions:

1. Can Worklight app issue USSD command from its code?
2. What about iOS that [prevents from programmatic use of * and # characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589344/dial-ussd-code-from-iphone-programatically)? Worklight documentation cleverly avoid answering this question saying that "Mobile user dials USSD code", [see documentation here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_ussd_support.html?lang=en).
3. What about IBM+Apple alliance, will it open extra possibilities for Worklight like programmatic USSD?

Answer (score 0):

For 1 and 2:

As you correctly noted, due the restriction of special character in iOS this is not possible.
The solution requires use of the phone's dialer. Hence Worklight does not provide an API to issue the USSD command programmatically.

Invoking the phone's dialer is a generic action that can be achieved using simple HTML and/or JavaScript.

For 3: Unknown.