# How to call a number which starts with * in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any way to call a number which starts with *? For example ***212*12345***? Normally the public APIs let us do it with numbers, but not with symbols.

Comment: why not just remove the `*` from the number?

Comment: The numbers might be [USSD codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data). Maybe.

Comment: Refer to the answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589344/dial-ussd-code-from-iphone-programatically) for some information.

Comment: @HotLicks I see numbers starting with `*` advertised all the time on interstates in the US .. EG "Call *77 for state police".  Ooops I take that back .. its `#77`.  My bad

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make phone calls with `*`. It is totally disallowed.

Have a look at the documentation on that [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html).

Comment: Disallowed by Apple or the service provider?

Comment: Apple. If I could find where I read it from in the documentation, I would link it.