# Loading a number with special characters in the dialler programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, ussd

I read from from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589344/dial-ussd-code-from-iphone-programatically) that Apple does not allow numbers with special characters * and # to be dialed programmatically for security reasons.

Can a number with special characters be loaded programmatically (displayed in dialer) so that the user has to simply press the call button?

I would like to emphasise that I just want the number to appear in the dialler programmatically without calling the number. This is different from some of the posts I've seen here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dial USSD code from iphone programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589344/dial-ussd-code-from-iphone-programatically)

Comment: I just updated the post